# How to achieve re sizable column in table in angular2

Tags: css, html, angular, webpack

I want to achieve a resizable column table in angular2 with webpack. I have already tried below approaches.

1) Using CSS property resize -> Problem with this is that it doesnot work in IE.

2) Using Jquery col resizable function -> Gives error that resizable is not a function.

Is there any other way to achieve this in angular2 + webpack. We have a HTML Table and want to resize a specific column without disturbing the others columns.